# Exclusive lock using key in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I have used the lock statement in C# to exclusively execute a piece of code. Is there a way to do same based on a key.

**for e.g.:**

```
lock(object, key)
{
//code-here
}
```

I have a method which has some piece of code that is not thread-safe, but only if the key (string) happens to be same in two parallel executions.  Is there a way to somehow accomplish this in .NET ?

If there is a way then we can have parallel executions if the key being used in the parallel executions is different and could improve performance.

Comment: How bout `if(key) { lock(object) {...}} else {...}` ?

Comment: @HariPrasad, Key is formed dynamically. There would be multiple of them. Also, using your snippet, how would I know if same key is being used across threads ?

Comment: Can't you just lock on the key itself? i.e. `lock (key)`

Comment: @BradleySmith - There's no guarantee that the key (`string`) would be the same reference even if they had the same value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put lock objects into dictionary indexed by the key - `Dictionary<string, object>` and grab objects by key to lock.

If you need to dynamically add new key/lock object pairs make sure to lock around the dictionary access, otherwise if after construction you only read values from dictionary no additional locking is needed.

Comment: In regards to your 2nd paragraph, you could use `ConcurrentDictionary` if that was necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I create a library called [AsyncKeyedLock](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncKeyedLock) which solves the problem. Internally it uses a `ConcurrentDictionary` and `SemaphoreSlim` objects.

In case you're using asynchronous code you can use:

```
using (await _locker.LockAsync(myObject.Id))
{
   ...
}
```

or if you're using synchronous code:

```
using (_locker.Lock(myObject.Id))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Was just thinking I don't want to spend the time writing the code to manage the ConcurrentDictionary of object locks, which, in my case, would otherwise grow pretty big :)